# C++ Eigen lib - eig(A,B) function computation time

Tags: c++, eigen

I just wanted to ask if someone could tell me the reason behind why my eig function computation time is different for the same size of matrices?

I am performing a lot of eig(A,B) operations on 4x4, 4x4 matrices to get eigenvalues and eigen vectors.

It happens 557 * 4 * 267 times.

```
std::pair<MatrixXcd, VectorXd> eig(const MatrixXcd& A, const MatrixXcd& B)
{
    Eigen::GeneralizedSelfAdjointEigenSolver<MatrixXcd> solver(A, B);

    MatrixXcd V = solver.eigenvectors();
    VectorXd D = solver.eigenvalues();

    return std::make_pair(V, D);
}

(...)

for (int t = 0; t < 557; t++)
{
    (...)
    for(int sig = 0; sig < 4; sig++)
    { 
        for(int f = 0; f < 267; f++)
        {
            // calculation of Xi and Xfs
            mRt = mXfs * mXfs.adjoint();
            mRj = mXfi * mXfi.adjoint();
            eValVec = eig(mRt, mRj);
            (...)
        }
        (...)
    }
}
```

For t<=7 eig computes 4 * 267 iterations in around 3 sec. 

For t>7 it suddenly becomes really fast and computes 4 * 267 iterations in ~0.1 sec.

I checked for sure that its eig that slows my program by commenting other parts of code and leaving only that function. I always use 4x4 matrices.

I guess important notice might be that all values or Rj matrix in t<=7 equals 0. So its like:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

While Rx has always values. After t>7 Rj also gain non zero values and computation becomes faster. So eig function might have problem to deal with zeros? I don't change anything related to eig function - only numbers in 4x4 matrices I insert to it changes. Still computation time differs. And this lag never happens after.

Do anyone have idea how could I fix it/debug it or make it more stable? I am doing processing in real time and 3 sec is quite too long for me.

Comment: this seems unlikely as `t` is not used in the calculations. I think your omitting some important part here.

Comment: I tried to create simplified version of my code as its quite huge. General idea is: t represents iteration with new starting data set. So it's like incoming data from the device. Each t iteration Xi and Xfs will have different values. I process incoming part of signal and save it to file. And repeat to go over it.

Comment: Can you try to get a minimum example running? What if the matrices are created randomly? Can you share your matrices?

Comment: Some ideas: (1) Measuring 0.1s intervals is already relatively short. Try measuring longer intervals/more iterations to get safe timings. (2) Start the loop with the nonzero matrices (maybe iterate backwards) and check if it still gets faster or if its really the zeros making trouble. (3) If it is always slow in the beginning, maybe your CPU frequency switches from powersave mode to power mode at some point? (4) If it is really the zeros, check if there is a special zero-matrix treatment in the eigen routine...